# Issue with a Process using '&&'

Tags: c#, .net, process

I have an external app with a number of arguments I need to run programmatically. It's all working fine in a command prompt but when I try to launch the same arguments from a .Net app, it fails. I've now learned it's the use of '&&' that is making the mess at the moment that some of the arguments has.

To simplify my question, say I have something like this working in my command prompt:

```
"Notepad.exe C:\tmp\tmp.txt && Notepad.exe c:\tmp\tmp2.txt"
```

This works fine. My attempt to achieve the equivalent looks like this:

```
string app = "Notepad.exe";
string args = @"C:\tmp\tmp.txt && Notepad.exe c:\tmp\tmp2.txt";
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(app, args)
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = false,
    };

    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

But this obviously does not work. Is my only option to split the arguments by '&&' and run them one by one or is there a way to make this work?

Comment: [Command line metacharacters are interpreted by the command intepreter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/16/598893.aspx). Your code just passes the whole command line to Notepad, and Notepad thinks that you merely passed it a very strange file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string args = @"C:\tmp\tmp.txt && Notepad.exe c:\tmp\tmp2.txt";
```

The reason is that `\` starts an escape sequence, meaning the text you pass as arguments is really this:

```
C:    mp    mp.txt && Notepad.exe c:    mp    mp2.txt
```

`\t` is the escape sequence for a tab.

The only difference between my code and your is the `@` in front of the string. This tells the compiler to interpret the string literally. If you need to know more, the name for this is "verbatim string".

---

**UPDATE:**
You can use this code:

```
string app = "cmd";
string args = @"/c Notepad.exe C:\tmp\tmp.txt && Notepad.exe c:\tmp\tmp2.txt";
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(app, args)
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
    };

    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

It will use cmd.exe to execute the compounded command. I changed `CreateNoWindow` to `true` to not show the command line window, but only the notepad windows.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot the escaping but it still doesn't work. Updated my question.

Comment: This won't achieve what he's aiming for, because 'process' will contain the cmd which can be terminated before the two notepads are. He must run notepad twice and wait twice.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: I don't understand your comment, but it is certainly working, I tested it. cmd exits after the second notepad has been closed.

Comment: Thanks

@YoryeNathan - The example worked for me. The idea is to wait for the first process to terminate before the second one is launched. This is how it behaves if I run it manually.

Comment: I'll explain better: process contains a reference to the process of the cmd, not the notepads. Once you run it, a cmd is open in the background (invisible) and it runs the first notepad. Now anyone can go to Window Task Manager and kill the cmd process, which will cause continuation of the code even though the notepad hasn't been closed (maybe not even the first one). It can also be killed in a different thread of code. More over - if killed before the 2nd notepad, the 2nd notepad will never run after the 1st one is exited (and all of that, while the code has long ago continued execution).

Comment: @BlueVoodoo That is why he must execute a separate proc for each notepad, so WaitForExit will actually wait for exit on the notepad. It sounds ugly but my answer has got it wrapped nicely, and it couldn't be cleaner than that.

Comment: @YoryeNathan - Thanks for the clarification. I agree, it would be cleaner but in this case, it doesn't matter too much. The cmd method will work just fine. The app will be running in a black box environment with nothing but the OS, this app and the thirdparty app for a number of days (a very low risk environment in other words). But good to know if I ever bump into this again.

Comment: Any other program can shut down the cmd, and so does a user via Windows Task Manager. All sorts of software require certain programs to be closed during updates or scans, etc. I would go safe, as it doesn't cost in efficiency nor readability.

Answer (score 1):

Have a method:

```
   private void RunAndWait(string app, params string[] args)
   {
       foreach (string arg in args)
       {
           Process proc = new Process
                          {
                              StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(app, arg)
                                              {
                                                  UseShellExecute = false,
                                                  CreateNoWindow = true
                                              }
                          };

           proc.Start();
           proc.WaitForExit();
       }
   }
```

And then the code very is simple:

```
   string app = "Notepad.exe";
   string args1 = @"C:\tmp\tmp.txt";
   string args2 = @"C:\tmp\tmp2.txt";
   RunAndWait(app, args1, args2);
```

And to generalize for more than two files (args):

```
   string[] args = new string[] {@"C:\tmp\tmp.txt", @"C:\tmp\tmp2.txt", ...}
   RunAndWait(app, args);
```

Comment: -1: **This** code doesn't do, what the OP wants! It starts both Notepad instances at the same time, not one after the other.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Updated my answer to run each notepad at a time. He would still have to run them separately to wait for them to exit correctly, so doing it in one line using the cmd is a bad idea.

Comment: Removed downvote. Care to explain, **why** it is a bad idea, because it certainly works.

Comment: Process.Start() will return the instance of the cmd itself. It can be shutdown manually even though it has no window, and then the program would think the notepads are killed when they really aren't. It is simply wrong to check if one parent process is alive as a condition whether his children are alive or not (as in this matter, when the cmd is terminated manually, the notepads won't be closed, because the cmd isn't really their "parent").

Comment: That's really only a theoretical concern. His code isn't killing the returned process, so this case isn't relevant for him.

Comment: An external program or even the user can do it themselves. It can happen. This more robust, independent (on cmd) and clean. Also, imagine wanting to run 10 notepads one after another. That is one pretty long cmd args line. The RunAndWait method is simply smart. Also just edited to add params to RunAndWait, which makes it even better.